# What is the alternative JAWT_GetAWT API?

Tags: java, c++, native

The **jawt.lib** necessray to link for using of JAWT_GetAWT API.

I createded native "C" dll through this way
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8b04ee324a1a/test/java/awt/JAWT/myfile.cpp

My java code is 
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8b04ee324a1a/test/java/awt/JAWT/MyCanvas.java

It is working fine in Window 7/8 64-bit OS with below code only.

For 32-bit OS, It gives below error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Rovet.Sen\Des
ktop\POC\U\MyCanvas-32.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

It works fines in window7 32-bit os.
Now it is not working in window8 32-bit OS.

So due to the random behavior of this dll, I am try to find out the alternative for of JAWT_GetAWT API.

Is there any way to write own code for this API?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the setting of the system property `java.library.path`?

Comment: Yes,Its give the correct path.

Comment: Are the same directories in this property for 32bit Win 7/8? Are you using a 64bit JVM on the 64bit Windows?

Comment: Are the same directories in this property for 32bit Win 7/8?-Yes  Are you using a 64bit JVM on the 64bit Windows? It work fine in 32 bit and 64 bit  JRE 6/7/8

Comment: Maybe there is another DLL before in the path. Could you check the installation following https://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm.

Comment: Window 8 is fresh system just install jre6 and test the application.Your suggested file is not present in JRE installation. Do you think in my case those file are required?

Answer (score -1):

As you don't tell which installation steps you did and where you get a problem. Find below the steps extracted from the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm) I already mentioned in the comment.

1. download the [Java Access Bridge](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jab-2-0-2-download-354311.html)
   as stated in the documentation, you don't need to for Java SE 7 Update 6 and later
2. install the files following the steps [Installing Java Access Bridge for Windows 32-Bit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/accessbridge/2.0.2/setup.htm#installing-jab-32-bit)
   install means here

   - unzip the file `accessbridge-2_0_2-fcs-bin-b06.zip`
   - copy the extracted files to the given directories
3. run your example code

If step 3. fails, please provide us a [MVCE - **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The same error in POC,Work in window7 -32 bit and not work in window8 -32 bit OS

Comment: I updated the question Please look it. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @mahen Ok. And how do you actually generate the `MyCanvas.h` and compile the `MyCanvas-32.c`. Does it work if you put the Java class and the DLL in the current directory when you start it?

Comment: MyCanvas.h created using javah.exe. MyCanvas-32.cpp create dll using visual studio 2015 using Win32 dll.

Comment: I already try to put this Mycanva-32.dll in the JRE installation path.But same error occur.